# Git saying I made changes in my code when I didn't, using Intellij IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Git constantly says: “Commit your changes or stash them before you can merge”?
when I didn't make any. If I try to stash them I get: "No local changes to save". If I compare the local file with the one in the repository then de IDE says "Contents are identical".
Does not work the git reset or the git revert.
I use Intellij IDEA (the same with the WebStorm) and the code is inside a Veracrypt's partition.

Any idea?

Comment: could you try a `git reset --hard`?

Comment: When you compare, do not ignore whitespaces and line-endings and see whether you get a diff then.

Comment: Finally this was solved when I started to use a superior version of the Intellij IDEA (2017.1.3). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since a file is listed in local changes in blue - it is definitely considered as modified. You could also execute `git status` manually and see its status.

Since diff shows you that contents are identical, most likely there are differences in line ending and/or formatting only, and you have the Diff tool configured to ignore relevant changes.

Make sure you have "Do not ignored" mode enabled in the Diff tool, also you could check the command line `git diff` is you are in doubt